# DateTimePicker maxDate parsing

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetimepicker

### Please help me. I feel like an idiot.

I'm trying to modify the script found in the DateTimePicker documentation to make sure that the start and end fields are linked together. I'm also using moment.js.

```
$("#startdate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
$("#enddate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#startdate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

I'm wanting to make it so that the user can't add an end date beyond the last day of the same year of the start date. Here's where I'm at.

```
$("#startdate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);

  var date = moment(e.date);
  var year = moment(date).year();
  var finalDate = moment(year + "-12-31");

  $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate("finalDate");
});
```

When I add a console log for each variable, this is what it looks like in the console along with the parsing error.

[image]

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try without quotes: $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(finalDate);

Comment: I think you are assigning finalDate wrong.correct way of doing it is var finalDate=moment([2016, 11, 31])

Comment: Oh my goodness. @BirgitMartinelle... it was the quotes. you know when you spend hours trying to modify everything and make it work, and then you feel ridiculously stupid, and then you get the answer (THANK YOU!) but it makes you feel even more stupid? yeah. that's me today.

I appreciate it greatly!